# Class 'App\NeoEloquent' not found

Tags: php, laravel, neo4j

I'm using Laravel 5 with NeoEloquent.
I did almost everthing configured according to instructions in this [Quick Reference](https://github.com/Vinelab/NeoEloquent),
I also created a model witch extends NeoEloquent
but when I use the model in my controller, I get the following error:

> Class 'App\NeoEloquent' not found

Do i did something wrong, or something misconfigured ?

Comment: Looks like you didn't import it at the top.

Comment: Could you paste your composer.json, app/config/app.php and the model code? (you can hide sensitive content).

Did you run composer update after editing the composer.json?

Try with `class Whatever extends \NeoEloquent` with the backslash.

Comment: @artberri : It seems to be solved now by adding backslash to ( class Whatever extends \NeoEloquent ). But whats wrong with that instruction on gitgub? In config/app.php , I had tried adding the NeoEloquent service provider before, as is said in the ReadMe file on NeoEloquent's GitHub but I did not work!

Comment: A lack in the documentation in my opinion, not your fault. Your model is probably in your namespace (App) so when you use NeoEloquent it thinks that it's  in your namespace so it does not find it. With the backslash you are saying that this class should be searched in the main namespace not inside `App`.

Comment: It isn't a lack of documentation, it is a lack of php knowledge. namespaces have been introduced in PHP5.3, more than 6 years ago, I don't think we need to write use statements for simple examples like this in 2015.